# Selecting posts together with optional taxonomy

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I want to select all (WordPress) posts together with the eventual `brand` and `brand_id` (both from the same taxonomy). If there is no brand set, the post should be selected anyway with these two fields set as `NULL`.

This query does almost work, but it's excluding posts that are missing a brand:

```
SELECT 
   p.ID AS post_id, 
   p.post_title AS title, 
   p.post_content AS body, 
   brand.name AS brand, 
   brand.term_id AS brand_id, 
   UNIX_TIMESTAMP(p.post_date) AS date_added 
FROM 
   wp_posts AS p 
INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships AS brand_rel
   ON brand_rel.object_id = p.ID 
INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy AS brand_tax
   ON brand_tax.term_taxonomy_id = brand_rel.term_taxonomy_id
   AND brand_tax.taxonomy = "product_brand" 
INNER JOIN wp_terms AS brand
   ON brand.term_id = brand_tax.term_id 
WHERE 
   p.post_type = 'product' AND 
   p.post_status = 'publish'
GROUP BY post_id;
```

Changing from `INNER JOIN` to `LEFT JOIN`, I get all the posts - but none of their brands (both `brand` and `brand_id` are `NULL`):

```
SELECT 
   p.ID AS post_id, 
   p.post_title AS title, 
   p.post_content AS body, 
   brand.name AS brand, 
   brand.term_id AS brand_id, 
   UNIX_TIMESTAMP(p.post_date) AS date_added 
FROM 
   wp_posts AS p 
LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships AS brand_rel
   ON brand_rel.object_id = p.ID 
LEFT JOIN wp_term_taxonomy AS brand_tax
   ON brand_tax.term_taxonomy_id = brand_rel.term_taxonomy_id
   AND brand_tax.taxonomy = "product_brand" 
LEFT JOIN wp_terms AS brand
   ON brand.term_id = brand_tax.term_id 
WHERE 
   p.post_type = 'product' AND 
   p.post_status = 'publish'
GROUP BY post_id;
```

If I however remove the `GROUP BY` statement during the `LEFT JOIN` I seem to get all the posts with and without a brand as I should, but also with alot of duplicates where most of the `brand` and `brand_id` fields are `NULL`.

All help appreciated.

Comment: This query is correct, it should work (I tried with another taxonomy I had on my site and it works).  Check if your `brand_tax.taxonomy` is correct. You can also chage `brand.name AS brand,` to  `group_concat(distinct brand.name separator ', ') AS brand,` and `brand.term_id AS brand_id,`  to `group_concat(distinct brand.term_id separator ', ') AS brand_id,` to get all of the brands and their ids if there are multiple.   http://i.imgur.com/UjoFyN9.jpg

Comment: `GROUP_CONCAT` seemed to do the trick. Doesn't feel like a clean solution, though, as it's simply concatenating null values. But it works - thank you!